# read() seems to go into infinite loop

Tags: c, linux

I am trying to read data from a socket. For some reason I cannot understand, it seems the read function goes into an infinite loop. The reason that's what I think happens is because while using eclipse to debug, the debugger does not get past the read function. Also, when I run the program with terminal, it runs forever. Help!!

Additional info: Running on Linux, and, not sure if has anything to do with this issue, but I create threads in the program.

Another something I think I should mention: The first time read() is called it works as expected and reads the whole message that's in the socket. The problem starts when read() is called again the second time (when there is nothing left to read). I expected that read would return 0 which would end the function, but instead, read goes into an infinite loop.

Here's where it's all happening:

```
read_write_res block_read_reply(int fd, void* buf, int max, int* read_size) {
int flag = 1;
if (read_size != NULL)
    *read_size = 0;
int i;
while (1) {
    i = read(fd, buf, max); /* HERE is where the debbuger gets stuck */
    if (i == 0 && flag == 1) //nothing to read
        continue;
    if (i == 0 && flag == 0)
        return READ_WRITE_SUCCESS;
    if (i < 0){
        return READ_WRITE_FAILURE;
    if (i > 0 && read_size != NULL)
        *read_size += i;
    }
    flag = 0;
    max -= i;
    buf = (char*) (buf) + i;
}
return READ_WRITE_SUCCESS;
```

}

Comment: `if (i == 0 && flag == 1) continue;` ... `man read` is your friend.

Comment: *"On success, the number of bytes read is returned (**zero indicates end of file**)"*

Comment: Note that on EAGAIN and EINTR errors, you should not return an error but try again.

Comment: @eyalm: `EAGAIN` cannot happen unless the socket is non-blocking, and in that case, immediately trying again is **not** what you should be doing. `EINTR` normally will not happen at all (unless you installed interrupting signal handlers), and if it does, whether to try again or consider it an error condition is not so clear-cut. Retrying on `EINTR` defeats the purpose of interrupting signal handlers, in which case you probably should have installed them with `SA_RESTART`...

Answer (score 8):

If `read` returns 0, it means you have reached end-of-file status. For a socket or pipe, this means there will be nothing more to read. EVER. So performing `continue;` in this case is definitely not what you want to be doing.

Comment: The above function is part of a server program. So the reason I put in that line is to prevent the server to read from the socket before any client has put a command there. That is, the server may run for an hour before any requests come in from clients, so I want the server to "busy wait" on the socket until at least one request has been given. Anyway, that is not where the program freezes. Again, it freezes at:
i = read(fd, buf, max)
Thanks for replying.

Comment: @user2016436 You must anyway fix that issue. If you're still stuck in read, after fixing this - maybe there's just no data to read. read() blocks until there is.

Comment: @nos After several hours on Google it indeed seems that there's no data to read, which makes read() block. How can I prevent calling read() when there is no data to read?

Comment: read() will return EAGAIN or EWOULDBLOCK if you set the socket to nonblocking and it doesn't feel like reading data immediately.  It can also return EINTR, in which case you should retry.

Comment: @user2016436: This is what `poll` (or the widely-used but inferior `select` function) is for.

Comment: @R.. I don't understand. What exactly does poll do (never heard of that function)? And how should I use it? As I said before, I think my main problem is calling read() when there is nothing left to read in the socket, because everything that was there has been read.

Comment: You asked "How can I prevent calling read() when there is no data to read?", and `poll` is the answer, but it's unclear to me whether you really even need to do this. If you're only dealing with one socket, and no other input that might be arriving asynchronously, then blocking is the behavior you want. The only definite problem I see in your code is that you're treating end-of-file (read returning 0) like a temporary condition that might happen before the data arrives. This is wrong. If read returns 0, the socket is no longer useful, and if you didn't already get your data, you never will.

Comment: @R.. I understand. Thanks. I've removed that statement (the one with "continue") but the problem persists. Any other ideas?

Comment: @user2016436 You just said the issue on hand is that there is no data to read - which is an entierly different problem that you need to think about how you need to handle for your particular case - there is already the siggestion of turning your socket to non blocking mode.

Comment: @nos Thanks!! Changing to non blocking did the trick. Now, instead of read() entering an infinite loop, it returns -1 and errno is set to EAGAIN. So I guess I should just ignore that as it means there is nothing more to read? Thanks again!

Comment: No. You did something completely different from what I and everybody else said. Please read again.